# Optimising a routine which contains calls to a very large list

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I have a large graph called `ndgraph` taken from some network data.

The following code builds a model of the data (the [nd.edu graph](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-NotreDame.txt.gz)) by 'growing' a graph in $n$ steps:

```
nd = Import["nd.txt", "Table"];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[nd], i++,
  nd[[i]][[1]] = nd[[i]][[1]] + 1;
  nd[[i]][[2]] = nd[[i]][[2]] + 1;
  ];(*Shifting by one, as a node 0 exists*)
ndgraph = Graph[nd];    
edgelist = ConstantArray[0, 1];
Ag = Graph[edgelist];
n = Length[VertexList[ndgraph]];
Ag = VertexAdd[Ag, 1];
lengthvertexlist = Length[VertexList[ndgraph]];
vd = VertexDegree[ndgraph];
sumofvertexdegrees = Sum[vd[[i]], {i, 1, lengthvertexlist }];
theta = RandomSample[Table[vd[[i]], {i, 1, lengthvertexlist }]];
norm = Abs[theta[[1]]];
k = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[#/2]] & /@ theta;

For[i = 2, i <= n, i++,
  VertexAdd[Ag, i];
  j = RandomChoice[
    1/norm theta[[Range[1, i - 1]]] -> Range[1, i - 1], {k[[i]]}];
  Ag = EdgeAdd[Ag, Thread[i <-> j]];
  norm = norm + theta[[i]];
];
```

For some reason, asking for certain values of `theta`, which has over a million elements from the beginning, is very slow.

Is there some way I can speed this up by removing calls to this list? Perhaps using `part` isn't a good idea?

Comment: Instead of `theta[[Range[1, i - 1]]]`, try `theta[[1;;i-1]]`. Apart from that, I don't think that the data requests to `theta` are the bottleneck. It is probably `VertexAdd` and `EdgeAdd`. Actually, you don't need to do that; you can also collect new vertices and edges in a `List` or in a `Internal`Bag` and add them in the end at once. Moreover, I would suggest consider to replace `For` by `Do`.

Comment: Btw.: a example graph that highlights the performance issues is missing.

Comment: I’ll add it, hang on

Comment: Minor improvement: `norm +=  theta[[i]];`

Comment: No problem. I’ll try using a replacement to edge add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime, I was able to create a `CompiledFunction` for the body of your long `For` loop (surprisingly, `RandomChoice` is compilable!):

```
cf = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {norm, _Real}, {k, _Integer}, {theta, _Real, 1}},
  Transpose[{
    Table[i, {l, 1, k}],
    RandomChoice[1./norm theta[[1 ;; i]] -> Range[1, i], {k}]
    }],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  Parallelization -> True
  ]
```

The following shows how you can retrieve, create, and process data a bit more efficiently. `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` takes rectangular arrays of integer, real, or complex numbers and tries to store them in a packed format that can be accessed quicker.

```
ndgraph = Graph[Developer`ToPackedArray[Import["nd.txt", "Table"]] + 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
theta = RandomSample[VertexDegree[ndgraph]]; // AbsoluteTiming
norms = Accumulate[theta]; // AbsoluteTiming
k = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[# 0.5]] & /@ theta; // AbsoluteTiming
results = cf[Range[VertexCount[ndgraph]], norms, theta, k + 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
edgelist = UndirectedEdge @@@ (Join @@ results); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {8.70484, Null}
>
> {0.082112, Null}
>
> {0.002379, Null}
>
> {9.34685, Null}
>
> {138.481, Null}
>
> {1.04823, Null}

I haven't run the original code, yet, so I cannot tell how these timings compare to it.

Some remarks:

- Adding `1` to a `List` `list` can quicker be done with `list + 1` than with a loop.
- I have to add `1` to the list `k` since compiled functions do not like empty lists `{}`. I do not know what the best way to get the original functionality would be.
- `cf` is parallelized. However, it manages to leverage only half the computational power of my quad core; proabably because the code in `cf` gets memory bound for large values of `i`.
- Joining of lists is done once in the end as well as the conversion to `UndirectedEdge`s: Each `Join` means a copy; `UndirectedEdge` unpacks arrays and leads to data structures that cannot be digested by `CompiledFunction`s.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and compile things and see how much faster it runs.

Comment: You're always welcome!

Comment: Yes, it now runs in a matter of seconds what previously took 6 hours, have edited my own answer to show how to achieve the original functionality.

Answer (score 2):

By creating a list of edges, which is the built with `Graph[edgelist]`, its an order of magnitude faster.

```
(*nd= Import["nd.txt","Table"];
For[i=1,i\[LessEqual]Length[nd],i++,
nd[[i]][[1]]=nd[[i]][[1]]+1;
nd[[i]][[2]]=nd[[i]][[2]]+1;
];
ndgraph=Graph[nd];*)
edgelist = {};
n = Length[VertexList[ndgraph]];
lengthvertexlist = Length[VertexList[ndgraph]];
vd = VertexDegree[ndgraph];
sumofvertexdegrees = Sum[vd[[i]], {i, 1, lengthvertexlist }];
theta = RandomSample[Table[vd[[i]], {i, 1, lengthvertexlist }]];
norm = Abs[theta[[1]]];
k = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[#/2]] & /@ theta;
For[i = 2, i <= n, i++,
  If[Mod[i, 1000] == 0, Print["Time = ", i];];
  j = RandomChoice[
    1/norm theta[[1 ;; i - 1]] -> Range[1, i - 1], {k[[i]]}];
  edgelist = Join[edgelist, Thread[i <-> j]];
  norm += theta[[i]];
  ];
```

EDIT: To modify using compile, as in Henrik's answer, we have

```
cf = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {norm, _Real}, {k, \
_Integer}, {theta, _Real, 1}}, 
  Transpose[{Table[i, {l, 1, k}], 
    RandomChoice[1./norm theta[[1 ;; j]] -> Range[1, j], {k}]}], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True]


SampleCount = 10000;
ndgraph = 
   Graph[Developer`ToPackedArray[Import["nd.txt", "Table"]] + 
     1]; // AbsoluteTiming
theta = RandomSample[VertexDegree[ndgraph], 
    SampleCount]; // AbsoluteTiming
norms = Accumulate[theta]; // AbsoluteTiming
k = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[# 0.5]] & /@ 
    theta; // AbsoluteTiming
results = 
   cf[Range[Length[theta]] + 1, Range[Length[theta]], norms, k + 1, 
    theta]; // AbsoluteTiming
results = 
   Delete[results[[#]], 1] & /@ Range[Length[theta]]; // AbsoluteTiming
edgelist = UndirectedEdge @@@ (Join @@ results); // AbsoluteTiming
nd100 = Graph[edgelist];
```

which outputs:

[image]

where the original functionality is achieved by removing the 1st added edge. The speed, as Henrik points out, is a matter of seconds, compared to the original 6 hours.

Comment: That's good to hear!